# Return type agnostic template class member function

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I have a class like:

```
tempate<class TReturn>
struct MyClass {
 template<class T>
 TReturn doSomething(const T &t) {
  // Do something
  return someValue;
 }
};
```

Now TReturn can be anything even void but in case it is void I want no return statement at the end and some minor different code in the function. What I want is a different function body depending on the return type. I'm using C++11 so if constexpr is not possible for me. Is there any way to to this in plain C++11?

Comment: You may have to specialize the template `template<>struct MyClass<void>` and rewrite the function as you want.

Comment: Note: You cannot overload functions on return type in C++.

Comment: You have no option in C++11 except to define a specialization when `TReturn` is `void`. You will likely have to drastically refactor this template classes, likely into several other helper classes, in order to avoid massive code duplication, but that's your only apparent option.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: you can with template functions, but then it is harder to call them

Comment: You can return void if you cast it to void. Something like return (T)someValue

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a specialization of your class for `void`:

```
tempate<>
struct MyClass<void> {
 template<class T>
 void doSomething(const T &t) {
  // Do something else
 }
};
```

If the class is in fact larger than you show and you want to specialize just this one function and not the whole thing, then a) it was probably unwise to make `TReturn` a parameter of the class when only a small part of the class depends on it, but b) there are ways to simulate that. E.g. you could sort of "partially specialize" the method by indirecting through a helper class (unlike function templates, class templates allow partial specialization). Something like this:

```
tempate<class TReturn> struct MyClass;

namespace internal {
  template <typename TReturn, typename T>
  class MyClassDoSomethingHelper {
    static TReturn Run(MyClass<TReturn>* that, const T &t) {
      // do something
      return someValue;
    }
  };

  template <typename T>
  class MyClassDoSomethingHelper<void, T> {
    static void Run(MyClass<void>* that, const T &t) {
      // do something else
    }
  };
}  // namespace internal

tempate<class TReturn>
struct MyClass {
 template<class T>
 TReturn doSomething(const T &t) {
   return internal::MyClassDoSomethingHelper<TReturn, T>::Run(this, t);
 }
};
```

Comment: That is a gold example. Thank you. Maybe it was unwise but this will be a simple state machine where the event dispatching may return a value or not depending on the use case. I didn't know how to do Vetter.